# CodeMirror fill Div and make Div 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, resize

Probably a solution that has been answered, but with all the wrong answers (aka, answers that do not solve this problem), it is very difficult to sift through to find the correct one.

The issue is this ---  How to make CodeMirror fill 100% of the parent div --- without forcing the rest of the page into 100% height as this causes the following issues :

When using

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

You are effectively telling the page that the entire height is the view port of the browser for the entire page including all contents.  The problem with this, is that I do not want everything on the page to be constrained to this proportion.  What I would like to do, is have normal access to the page without breaking responsiveness (aka, mobile, etc support), and still have a single div on the page (right panel) have a div that ONLY THAT div is 100% height --- of the space in that div.  I do not want 100% height to overflow into the menu, go underneath/over the menu, etc.  It must stay within the box.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this attribute :

```css
/* Firefox */
height: -moz-calc(100vh - 190px);
/* WebKit */
height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 190px);
/* Opera */
height: -o-calc(100vh - 190px);
/* Standard */
height: calc(100vh - 190px);
```

Using **calc** combined with **vh** allows you to constrain the size of the element to the visible area.

Comment: That is a very handy command  ( vh ) ... however what happens is the CodeMirror box is sized to the Veiwport Height, and not the height of the container it is in -- meaning that CodeMirror is sized so that the exact height of the contents above it is what is scrollable off the page.  Is there a way to calculate the difference of the top element height and vh automatically.  This is responsive.

Comment: Try using the parent div's margin:0; and use the child div height:100%;

Comment: doing that really buggers things.  CodeMirror still goes off the page, AND overlaps the left menu.  It also forces my header to align all elements to the left retaining the height.  Is there someway to use css3 to get the height of another div by it's selector -- and use that in a calculation -- that would work i'm sure.  All google results are pointing to javascript only, but i am sure this can be done.

Comment: I made a change to your Post.  Please accept it as your answer helped lead me into a solution, however it is not working solution as you originally posted.

Comment: calc is hacky nasty solution.